Cross-referencing of modified item list
Is it possible to cross-reference items using a modified item list? For example, name1 should appear in the body text. I have not found a solution so far (I tried enumitem)
 \documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
   \item[name1] item1 
   \item[name2] item2
   \item[name3] item3
\end{itemize}

\end{document}


@AlanMunn many thanks for your comment, this question was helpful!
